# Python Challenge Solution

Tags: python

I was taking part in a Python challenge and this question came up, hope you can help.

**Input**

**1st line:**  N, number of contestants to select

**2nd line:** P, number of problems

**3rd line:** P integers, the difficulty of each problem

**4th line:** C number of contestants

**5th line:** C integers, ability of each contestant

Contestants can solve problems whose difficulty is not higher than their ability

**Output**

`Print 'yes'` if we can find top N contestants, `else print 'no'`.

**Example**

**Input :** `1 2 5 10 3 5 9 10`

**Output:** `'yes'`

**My attempt:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())  
    P = int(input())  
    P_diff = list(map(int, input().split())) 
    assert len(P_diff) == P
    C = int(input())  
    exp = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(exp) == C
    assert not N > C

    a = 0 
    for k in P_diff:
        for l in exp:
            while l >= k:
                a += 1

    if C - a == N:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Comment: could you please describe us the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this python challenge problem, my attempt doesn't seem to be working in all cases

Comment: @mij09, which bit of your code doesn't work?

Comment: well it definitely is a challenge then

Comment: When it runs against the test cases it doesn't pass all of them. I'm wondering if someone can spot a problem with it?

Comment: what is `p_diff` and `exp` ?

Comment: p_diff = difficulty of each problem
exp = ability of each contestant

Comment: Its a list right ? So how many elements you want to add on it ?

Comment: len(p_diff) == P 

and 

len(exp) == C

Comment: Then why can't you do `P_diff = list(int(input()) for i in range(P))` like this ?

Comment: Do that not achieve the same thing?

Comment: yeah I know But doing by the way in your code will add only one element. You have to also change that `while` to `if` with the above change. with that when i tried its working. But I don't understand what you mean by *"find top N contestants"*

Comment: @mij09 `print  "yes"` if the number of contestants who can solve the problem, is equal to N or greater than N ,,,Is that you mean ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar N is the number of people that we want to select (to go through to the next round). So if we are trying to find 2 people (N = 2) and only 1 person has the ability to solve the problems, print('no'). However print('yes') if the input will allow us to select the top_N contestants

Comment: @mij09 So `a` is the number of peoples who can solve problems right ?  What it should prints if  N=3 in your above condition

Comment: @VikasDamodar ye 'a' is the number of people that can solve every problem. But I don't think my method is a good way of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding about your problem i have made some changes in your code its working, Just try it and check whether it meets your requirements or not :

```
N = int(input())
P = int(input())
P_diff = list(int(input()) for i in range(P))
assert len(P_diff) == P
C = int(input())
exp = list(int(input()) for j in range(C))
assert len(exp) == C
assert not N > C
a = 0
a = sum([a+1 for x in P_diff for y in exp if x >= y])
if a >= N:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

If its working for your needs may be we can make changes in this code and make it more efficient way.

**UPDATION :**

If you want to take the elements for that array in single line you can do like this :

```
P_diff = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(P_diff)
```

It take input like : `5 10 11` and prints like :

```
[5, 10, 11]
```

**EDIT :**

IF you want to give all the inputs in a single line at first here a way you can do :

```
li = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(li)


N = li[0]
P = li[1]
P_diff = list(li[i] for i in range(2, 2+P))
assert len(P_diff) == P
C = li[2+P]
exp = list(li[j] for j in range(3+P, 3+P+C))
assert len(exp) == C
assert not N > C
a = 0
a = sum([a+1 for x in P_diff for y in exp if x >= y])
if a >= N:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Here the input you can give like : `1 2 5 10 3 5 9 10` in a single line (do not give with ' ' like a string)

Comment: P_diff = list(int(input()) for i in range(P))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5 10'

Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: the error is due to the fact that `int('5 10')` cannot be converted because is not a valid number

Comment: @mij09 you have to give the input numver one by one..not together like a string

Comment: @VikasDamodar Ok thanks its working now. Is there any way to have multiple inputs on the one line?

Comment: @mij09 are you mean to give all the input values(includes N, P , P_diff, C...) through a single line ?